# Facebook API - simple integration - WALL + Like Box

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-wall

I would like to display my wall (of my facebook) on my website.
But, I would also like to add a like box next to it.

It seems, however, that I cannot have **both**, because: 
It seems that, once the user logs in (after pressing the LIKE button), my website looses the login and my wall can't display the information anymore.

As anyone had done this before? If so, how do you manage to make it work?

Comment: Please add a link to your site.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it looks to me that you are mixing two logins:

- Login 1 - your login (to have access to YOUR wall)
- Login 2 - user login (to have access to user actions)

You just need to keep them both: read you wall with your login, and let user act under user login parameters